# Running Java project ONLY if all Junit tests passed OK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I'm running a project in Java which is configured to first run the JUnit test class (it is a class with parameterized tests) and only then build the project itself and run it.

Is there a way to configure Intellij to run the build of the project only if the tests of Junit passed successfully ?

Thanks

Comment: Would you consider a build tool with a project lifecycle like maven?

Answer (score 1):

In intellij in 'run/debug configurations' -> 'before launch' -> '+' -> 'run another configuration'. The last may be your unit tests ('all in module_name').

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to run in first JUnit test from your main app and check result, if error you exit app :

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
Result result = junit.run(testClasses);

if (!result.wasSuccessful()) {
                LOG.fatal("Some JUnit Text Failed, app will exit");
                System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: The probelm is that my Junit class invokes the main method of the project in order to produce a certain result. That means the the code above will cause an infinite loop (because the main and the Junit will call each other back and forth). Maybe i will have to use a flag in that case to distinguish the caller which will be passed thru main args... (?)

Comment: I know, this will make cyclic dependensies, however it's not a really good think to call main from JUnit